Regex to substitute the next two words after a matching point
I'm writing a Regex to substitute the maximum of the next two words after the matching point.
Expected prefixes: dr, doctor, pr, professor
Sample text:

Examination carried out in agreement with and in the presence of Dr
John Doe (rhythmologist).

Expected outcome:

Examination carried out in agreement with and in the presence of Dr
[DOCTOR_NAME] (rhythmologist).

Here is my current Regex:
(\s|^|^(.*)|\()(dr|doctor|pr|professor)(\s|[.])(\s*([A-Z]\w+)){0,2}

However, it doesn't account for an ending parenthesis, as shown in the following image:

Really appreciate the help to improve the Regex. Thank you!

What exactly are you trying to match and what is the intended substitution (if any) ?

@TimBiegeleisen I am trying to match one of "dr, doctor, pr, professor" in a text by substituting "[DOCTOR_NAME]" with the following two words.

Are you guaranteed that "Dr." is always followed by first and last name in your source text?

@MonkeyZeus No it can be only first name too, I am wondering how to handle this conditionally.

You seem to be making this more complicated than it has to be.  You want to match a doctor/professional title, either as a full word or abbreviation, followed by 1 or 2 word names.  Then use this pattern:
\b(dr|doctor|pr|professor)\b[.]?\s+(\w+(?: \w+)?)

and replace with this:
$1 [$2]

Demo
Explanation of pattern:

\b(dr|doctor|pr|professor)\b match title
[.]? optional dot
\s+ one or more whitespace characters
(\w+(?: \w+)?) then match and capture in $1 one or two word names


I think that output for dr Martin Smith should be dr [DOCTOR_NAME].

This will match the next two words after the professor. and doctor. too. Example: "What is the C constant?" - student asked the professor. The child was curious. Will match professor. The child

Stop right there.  Regex isn't suitable for parsing grammar.  To do that, you need a specialized library.  My answer above is valid per your original problem statement, which assumes that you know that the next 1 or 2 words belong with the dr./prof. title.

I just pointing out that the optional dot will work for professor and doctor too. And usually, only dr and pr might have a dot before the name. So maybe \b(dr\b[.]?|doctor|pr\b[.]?|professor)\s+(\w+(?: \w+)?) is a bit better. But I agree, one should be sure that for every single case of the words matched what comes after is what you want.

@MuslimbekAbduganiev Agree with your second comment...I rushed to answer and did not notice that not all terms are abbrevations.

To somewhat reduce the risk for false positives, maybe only match a dot after an abbreviation, and only match words which begin with an uppercase character.
re.sub(
    r'\b((?:[Pp]rofessor|[Dd]octor|[DdPp]r\.?)\s+)([A-Z](?:\.|\w*)(?:\s+[A-Z]\w*)?)\b',
    r'\1[DOCTOR NAME]',
    input_text)

I would perhaps also include [Pp]rof\.? in the alternatives; I have never seen "professor" abbreviated as "Pr."
This will obviously still fail for Professor van Helsing, Doctor de Havilland, Prof. fforbes-Lloyd, Dr. J. R. R. Tolkien, etc. Perhaps see also Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names
Demo: https://ideone.com/oPhcNP
